# Python mailbox remove replies

Tags: python, mbox

I'm using the python mailbox module to load a series of email messages. Is there an easy way to cut out all but the most recent message in an email? Different clients seem to treat the text of replies differently, so I can't find a single way to filter them out that would work for all of the emails.

Is there a way to do this built-in to the mailbox module? Here's the code I'm running to get the emails, and print out the plain text part to an output file:

```
import mailbox

def main():
    text = ""
    for message in mailbox.mbox('test.mbox'):
        text += str(getPayload(message))

    with open('output.txt','wb') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(text)
        outputfile.close()

def getPayload(msg):
    body = ''
    if msg.is_multipart():
        for part in msg.walk():
            ctype = part.get_content_type()
            cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))

            if ctype == 'text/plain' and 'attachment' not in cdispo:
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                break

    else:
        body = msg.get_payload(decode=True)

    return body

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Is there a way to get only the newest message in a chain?

Answer (score -1):

You can see the body of Email has to part :
- Mail
- previous mail in chain

Like this

```
Re: Do Smthg

ok,i ll do it

On Fri, Oct 5, 2018 at 6:10 PM abc <abc@.edu.vn>
wrote:

> Hi X
>
> Can you do this for me
> 
> ABC
> ---------- Forwarded message ----------
> From: ...
> Date: 3 October 2018 at 16:34
> Subject: Do Smthing
```

The mail body is "okai, i ll do it"
So, to get the newest part of Mail, just remove parts contain "> " symbol